# regular expression or replace function in where clause of a mysql query

Tags: regex, mysql

I write a mysql query

```
select * from table where name like '%salil%'
```

which works fine but it will no return records with name 'sal-il', 'sa@lil'.

So i want a query something like below

`select * from table where`**remove_special_character_from(name)**`like '%salil%'`

**remove_special_character_from(name)** is a mysql method or a regular expression which remove all the special characters from name  before like executed.

Answer (score 1):

No, mysql doesn't support regexp based replace.
I'd suggest to use normalized versions of the search terms, stored in the separate fields.

So, at insert time you strip all non-alpha characters from the data and store it in the `data_norm` field for the future searches.

Answer (score 1):

Since I know no way to do this, I'd use a "calculated column" for this, i.e. a column which depends on the value of `name` but without the special characters. This way, the cost for the transformation is paid only once and you can even create an index on the new column.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45372/calculated-columns-in-mysql-on-insert-statements) how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [Aaron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34088/aaron-digulla) and [Col. Shrapnel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285587/col-shrapnel) that you should use an extra column on the table e.g. `search_name` to store a normalised version of the name.

I noticed that this question was originally tagged ruby-on-rails. If this is part of a Rails application then you can use a [before_save](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html#M002139) callback to set the value of this field.

Answer (score 0):

In MYSQL 5.1 you can use `REGEXP` to do regular expression matching like this

```
   SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar REGEXP "baz"
```

see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

However, take note that it will be **slow** and you should do what others posters suggested and store the clean value in a separate field.